# Computer freezes when playing youtube video in Chrome

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, freeze, youtube

I have got a computer with fresh 14.04 installation. Whenever I open a Youtube video in Chrome it plays for a minute or so, and the the machine freezes. The only way out of it is a hard reset.

I have had a short look into dmesg and syslog but nothing caught my eye. Any clue in which log file should I look for an answer?

I have tried Firefox, and works fine there.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be a hardware problem - graphic card fan was packed with dust, and graphic-costly operations (like watching videos) caused it to overheat. I found that out when it was already too late and I needed to replace the graphic card. After replacing it the problem was gone.

Comment: if hardware was the issue then any ideas why Firefox didn't freeze the computer? I'm experiencing the same problem.